# Как продолжить парсить с помощью Jsoup

Tags: android, парсер, jsoup

Есть сайт с которого происходит парсинг. Но дело в том что данные на сайте подгружаются при нажатии на кнопку. В jsoup парситься только данные которые сейчас на странице. Как спарсить подгружаемые данныекоторые на сайте после нажатия на кнопку?

[Вот ссылка на сайт](http://m.vesti.az)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего при нажатии на кнопку выполняется какой то javascript код который подгружает данные.Сам jsoup не может интерпретировать js.

Гугл предлагает юзать [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

А так можно посмотреть еще [здесь варианты](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jsoup%20javascript%20execute).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.